# VBA - Excel (2013) How to 'Find' the same value in each sheet but replace with a different value in each sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with 93 budgets in (one per sheet). These sheets use vlookups to pull the values other budget Excel files. I created the sheets by making duplicates of the original budget sheet and then renaming them.

Currently, all the sheets are now looking up values from the same file, but I need them to lookup the values from the different files. The range from which the lookups occur are the same in each of the 93 budget files. I'd like to do a find and replace that looks for the same value in each tab (budgetcode.xlsx) and replaces it with a new value that differs per sheet.

I found the code below which works for 1 sheet, and I would need to run this 93 times (which takes a while in this workbook). Is there a way to update it to run for all 93 sheets and replace the 'budgetcode' with the value in a certain cell in each sheet?

```
Sub Macro1()

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Range("E3:CN9254").Select
Selection.Replace What:="", Replacement:="0", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.CalculateFull

End Sub
```

Any help will be much appreciated!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) with **their** code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. If you don't have any code yet then you might be asking on the wrong site.

Comment: Are there any values in the individual sheets that are unique? Maybe you can use those values instead of the sheet name?

Comment: Hi Ralph. I'll update the post with code shortly.

Comment: Hi Neal. Yes, there is a cell in each sheet that is unique. It contains a string value of the budget code. The files are named with the budget code. I've tried using the indirect function in a formula, but this requires the file to be open for it to work, which is where I ran into the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should give you a really nice shell. I made some obvious assumptions that you'll need to change to reflect your actual data structure. The only caveat I can think of at the moment is to ensure that when you replace the file names to make sure that the filepath exists on your drive, otherwise, you'll get a very long list of annoying pop-ups looking for a valid file path for each item to replace.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChangeFileNameInFormula()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws as Worksheet
For each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    Dim sBudgetCode as String
    sBudgetCode = ws.Range("A1") 'change to the cell that contains the budget code

    ws.Range("E3:CN9254").Replace What:="OriginalFileName", Replacement:=sBudgetCode, LookAt:=xlPart

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @ScottHoltzman. I tried it, but it started searching for sBudgetCode.xlsx. I assume this is because the inverted commas make it input a the string "sBudgetCode" in the cells and not referencing the cell reference defined in the code as sBudgetCode. I've removed the inverted commas around sBudgetCode and it is running. I'll post the result shortly.

Comment: Thanks for the shell code. It worked (with removing the inverted commas around sBudgetCode and adding "ws" after "next"), but because Excel was linking to external files and was doing this around 7200 per worksheet, this took forever. After 24 hours, it still was not done. I then cancelled it and redid the code to only do the top left cell in table for each worksheet. Then I used a macro to copy and paste the formula to the rest of the cells and was done in 20 minutes. Thanks for the assistance!